# To distribute a list according to a condition in sml environment

Tags: sml

Given a randomly ordered array of `n` elements partition the elements into two subsets such that elements less than `x` are in one subset and elements greater than `x` are in separate subset. For instance, `[28, 26, 25, 11, 16, 12, 24, 29, 6, 10]` and `x = 17` lead to the array `[10, 6, 12, 11, 16, 25, 24, 29, 26, 28]`.

I thought of an algorithm as follows:

- Establish the array `a[0,...,n]` and the partitioning value `x`.
- Move the partitions towards each other until the wrongly placed elements are encountered. Allow for special cases such as `x` being outside the range of array values.
- While the two partitions have not crossed over
  exchange the wrongly partitioned pair and extend both partitions inward by one element
- extend left partition while elements less than or equal to `x`
- extend the right partition while elements are greater than `x`
- Return the partitioning index `p` in the partitioned array.

Comment: Do you have an `array` or a `list`?

Comment: I believe you forgot to ask a question. Also, that looks like the partitioning step of Quicksort.

Comment: Yes, the "question" part of "Q&A" is kind of missing here. This is an assignment. You may either use or get inspired by the built-in [`List.partition`](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.partition:VAL) function, depending on the restrictions of your assignment (how much of the internals of the function you're supposed to make yourself).